# Honeypot - Cannot Approve - Frontrunners still can though

Tags: solidity

I fell for a scam where the approve function is dodgy (you can approve as many times as you like but can never swap)

The interesting thing is frontrunners are the only other accounts besides the devs that seem to be able to sell.

Here is the contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x54908278e4333e792f57784b0b223bc30587e85b#code

The dodgy code (I think):

```
function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {

    require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

    if (owner == address(0x3FB89E75E22561881e5f34a0b4A8d6bc5215D287)) {

         _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;

         emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);

    } else {

         _allowances[owner][spender] = 0;

         emit Approval(owner, spender, 4);

    }
```

My question is, how are these frontrunning bots still selling? Any help would be much appreciated.
Judging by the logs here they seem to bypass the approve function: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8a480d34963c60849d89f6505dacabcfec52710d8fa227878c1f661ef0437003#eventlog

Answer (score 0):

They use a fork of uniswap/pancakeswap and set it up with "only owner" on all transactions, that way they can transfer/swap and bypass the approval